# How to change the variable name of annotate query inside for loop?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-queryset

I don't know if I hit the right question for my problem.

In my query, I wanted to dynamically change the name of the annotate name depends on its hazard level. But I can't seem to get it. It just returns the name itself which is "hazard_level".

The problem it this line `.annotate(hazard_level=Count('brgy_locat')))`. How do I get those hazard level then use it as the name of the annotate query. So that the JSON out will be like this:

```
[
        {
            "Low": 2,
            "brgy_locat": "Barangay 9",
            "municipali": "Cabadbaran City"
        },
        {
            "High": 5,
            "brgy_locat": "Comagascas",
            "municipali": "Cabadbaran City"
        }
        ...
]
```

Here's my code:

```
    if request.method == "GET":
    # create a list
    to_json = []

    # this code is results a messy JSON data that need underscore.js to manipulate
    # in order for us to use datatables
    hazard_levels = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low']
    for hazard_level in hazard_levels:
        reference = FloodHazard.objects.filter(hazard=hazard_level)
        ids = reference.values_list('id', flat=True)
        for myid in ids:
            getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
            response = list( PolyStructures
                        .objects
                        .filter(geom__within=getgeom)
                        .values('brgy_locat', 'municipali')
                        .annotate(hazard_level=Count('brgy_locat'))
                       )
            to_json.append(response)    

    return HttpResponse(list(json.dumps(to_json)), 
                        content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: was my answer a solution or useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is a code less approach:

```
    response = list( PolyStructures
                        .objects
                        .filter(geom__within=getgeom)
                        .values('brgy_locat', 'municipali')
                        .annotate(hazard_level=Count('brgy_locat'))
                       )
    response_cooked = [ { ( "high" if x.hazard_level >= 5 
                                   else "low" 
                          ) : x.hazard_level,                                     
                            "brgy_locat": x."brgy_locat", 
                            "municipali": x.municipali  
                         }
                         for x in response 
                       ]
    to_json.append(response_cooked)
```